# Audio library for c#

Tags: c#, open-source, audio

I'm searching for library that has those features:
- can save and load from wav files, compression to/from Mp3 is an option but not necessary
- give me possibility to change speed, volume and tone of part of audio file
Do you know such open source library that I can use in C# application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) has all or at least most of those features.

Comment: It’s late to contribute to this question, but [NAudio (now at GitHub)](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio)—albeit having example code for changing audio speed—in turn makes use of the [SoundTouch](http://soundtouch.surina.net) library. The latter one makes everything LGPL, which might be a drawback for some applications.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/), you might look into [BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/).  There is a solid .NET wrapper for it, and plenty of example code to get started for a number of audio tasks.